# Contribute permissions for specific parts of a site

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-online

We're assessing SharePoint to use for our intranet site.

I want specific groups of users to be able to edit some hierarchies of content but not others.  For example, HR contributors should be able to edit pages in the HR area of the site but not the  Customer Service pages.

I've looked at doing this by:

- Creating a wiki pages library for each area of the site - looks like
  it would be the simplest way of doing it but I can't see a way of
  setting specific permissions for a wiki library
- Creating a new pages library (like 'SitePages') - site pages has
  options for setting permissions but I can't find a way of creating a
  pages library like this, only the wiki pages library.
- Creating a new site collection for each of the areas of my site. 
  This was suggested in a guide I read but seems a bit heavy handed.

What is the simplest way of doing this?  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set permissions at the list/library level, but I think I would agree with the guide and create a new site collection for each site.

Dealing with future requirements is then probably easier and permission inheritance is cleaner as you're not breaking inheritance for specific lists.

The following article is very useful - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262778.aspx